# Monitoring StarCluster / Sun Grid Engine Cluster Performance

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, sungridengine, starcluster

I am a bit new to using StarCluster and SGE.  I was wondering what the best practice is for monitoring "Cluster Performance", that is, to determine how many of a certain job the cluster can run in some unit of time.  I am familiar with qstat command but that just shows the status of each job.  I guess my use case is to submit X jobs and to know how long it takes for all X to complete.  Is there an easy out-of-the-box way to do this or must I write a scipt to do it?

Right now I am using Ubuntu 12.04 for each instance.

Thanks Much!

Comment: Your question is not too clear to me. What do you want to do with that monitoring? Add and remove nodes based on the "performance"? If so, you should look into StarCluster loadbalance.

Comment: Just want to easily estimate execution time for a set of jobs and try different configurations of the cluster to see what is most efficient.   So, I'm really just wanting to time a set of jobs and know when they all complete.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash script like this one + a time command should suffice then.

```
lines=999
while [ $lines -ne 0 ]; do
    sleep 1;
    lines=`qstat -u "*" | wc -l`;
    done;
```

This script will loop as long as the queue is not empty. If you call your script "queue_watch.sh", then start you jobs and then run the command

```
time bash queue_watch.sh
```

And that should do it.